# col-md-6 is not responsive on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I have the following section on the desktop, and I need to make in mobile the image is above and the orange box is down, but the image is getting over everything.

**Desktop**

[image: DESKTOP]

**MOBILE**
[image: how is doing in mobile]

```css
.second-section .box-orange {
  background-image: url("/img/fundo2.png");
  height: 400px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.second-section .box-orange img {
  height: 550px;
  margin-top: -10%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.second-section .box-orange h3 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-bottom: 5%;  
}

.second-section .box-orange h3 .line {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-bottom: 5%;  
}

.second-section .box-orange p {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-bottom: 5%;  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section class="second-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center box-orange">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="w-100" src="img/campos.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 ml-5 ml-md-0 text-center">
        <h3>lorem lorem! <div class="line"></div>
        </h3>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum nulla quod alias odio perspiciatis architecto, possimus, aliquid repellendus totam, quos nihil similique. Laborum eaque ipsa beatae amet sapiente temporibus. Rerum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

I do not know if I should structure my CSS differently or do some kind of media want to stay the way I need it.

Need to stay like this in mobile.

[image: mobile]

---

### After adding the media, the result was that.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 .second-section img {
  height: unset;
  margin-left:unset;
}

 .textdiv {
  margin-left:0px;

}
}
```

[image: result after media querie]

Comment: Have you written any media querry? If not then remove position absolute in medai querry and it will work for mobile device

Comment: please add CSS on SO, dont add scss here

Comment: 1) bootstrap grid is distributed into 12 columns
2) class : col-xs-6 represents ( 6 columns for eXtra Small device like mobile )
  col-sm-6 represents ( 6 Columns for Small devices like Ipad
col-md-6 ( 6 columns for medium device ) and so on.. 
3) So to fix this you can use appropriate class, it will work

Comment: col-xs-6 not working,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="second-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row align-items-center box-orange">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img class="w-100" src="img.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 ml-md-0 text-center textdiv">
                    <h3>lorem lorem! <div class="line"></div></h3>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum nulla quod alias odio perspiciatis architecto, possimus, aliquid repellendus totam, quos nihil similique. Laborum eaque ipsa beatae amet sapiente temporibus. Rerum.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>  
    </body>    
</html>
```

CSS :

My.css:

```
.box-orange {
background-image: url("/img/fundo2.png");
height: 400px;
color: white;
margin-top: 10%;
margin-bottom: 10%;
}
.second-section img {
  height: 550px;
  margin-top: -10%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.second-section h3 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.second-section.line {
    width: 80%;
    border: 2px solid #77d3c2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 33%;
    top: 100%;
  }

  .second-section p {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding: 0% 10%;
}
.textdiv {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .second-section img {
      height: unset;
      margin-left:unset;

    }

    .textdiv {
      margin-left:0px;

    }
}
```

Because you've given image fixed height and that same height is applied to the mobile version also, To fix that I've included Media query

Check it out, It'll work

Comment: add col-xs-6 in that place